# How can I deploy a create-react-app through npm?

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment

When I try to deploy a CRA with `npm run build` everything works fine, but when I head to localhost:5000, I get 404 Requested path could not be found, and in dev. console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

How should I deploy my CRA's? 
Everything works fine on development build.

Comment: No, it's deployed on localhost:5000

Comment: what's CRA? client react application?

Comment: @OscarRyz It means Create-React-App, and it refers to the command used to create the first packages for React.js apps ;)

Answer (score 1):

The fact was:
The terminal told me to use `serve -s build` but it failed when was ran from the /build folder.
When I run `serve -s` from inside of the /build folder, everything is working properly!

Cheers!